# How do i make jmeter set number of threads (users) automatically according to the number of requests per second?

Tags: java, multithreading, testing, jmeter

If i want to run a test with 10 Requests Per Second. How to make Jmeter choose the best number of threads needed to handle that number of requests per second.

I set the number of threads to be the same as number of requests per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a constant throughput timer [click here](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer)
and you would just need to convert since it is based on throughput per minute.  So yours would be 10*60 = 600 requests per minute.  However, it also depends on if the server can handle the load or not.